How to resize an image in redmine so it will show up, properly resized, when a pdf is produced from the issue?
Running redmine 5.0.1 on ubuntu 22.04, we have issues containing large images.  We are using text formatting style "CommonmarkMarkdown". If those images are referenced as
<img src="filename.jpg" width="70%">

they display resized properly in the issue, but when a pdf is produced from the issue, the images are missing.
If the images are referenced as
![](filename.jpg)

the images display (oversized, too big) in the issue, and also appear (oversized, too big) in a pdf produced from the issue.
This answer implies that the expression
![](filename.jpg){width="70%"}

is now accepted in gitlab markdown, but I can't get that to work in redmine 5.0.1.
Is there a way to use the CommonmarkMarkdown in Redmine with images resized, and also have the pdf produced from an issue show the resized images?

This works for me:
!{width:25%}image_url!
